# Ag grid - Nested Master/ detail Custom Grids

Tags: ag-grid

Has anyone been able to successfully render a grid 3 layers of nested custom grids?

The 2nd level master detail and the 3rd level master detail are rendered using the Cell Renderer Component. The struggle I'm dealing with is how to get the 1st level grid to dynamically adjust the height to accommodate the 2nd and 3rd level master-detail grids?

I've tried the AutoHeight in gridOptions for the 1st level grid.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?  Preferably with a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example